# Gnome clock applet, where's the data stored?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, date-time

I mean, when I type location it gets GMT +/- fixes, were does that information come from?

Answer (score 1):

Linux (and UNIX in general) systems usually keep the hardware clock in UTC.

Then, there is a system-wide time zone setting usually implemented as `/etc/localtime`, copied from or linked to some file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, which provides information on how to convert the UTC time value to a local date and time. This provides a default for all users' processes. Some distributions make /etc/localtime a symbolic link, and some (presumably for resilience in case /usr/share is unavailable) make an outright copy.

Then, a (user or system) process can set the `TZ` environment variable to override this default. Such a setting will be inherited according to the normal environment-inheritance rules, which can be exploited to set the default time zone for a specific user separately from the system default. For multi-user systems with users spread out across time zones, this is a very useful property since each user will see the time he/she expects.

So, there isn't really a *single* place in which to look for the information you want.